Unable to find class in file
Unknown Class - yii\\baselUnknownClassException
Unable to find 'app|components|GlobalComponent' in file: 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/harmony-cdn/components/GlobalComponent.php. Namespace missing?

I have class GLobalComponent in folder components, and I wrote down the directory app\components\GlobalComponents in the config file. But it doesn't see this class and make this exception
I checked for misspellings, but everything was okay

Try checking if there is proper namespace declaration in that GlobalComponent.php file and that there is no typo in namespace. Also, I assume those | in class name are just something that happened when you were writing the question. If not, the correct namespace separator is \  not |.
